# Graphviz error - how do I view a graph with Python 3.3?

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

I am working with Python 3.3 ([Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_%28Python_distribution%29) distribution), and I would like to display a graph using [Graphviz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphviz).

You'll find below what I'm trying to do:

```
from graphviz import Digraph

g = Digraph('G', filename='hello.gv')

g.edge('Hello', 'World')

g.view()
```

Here's the error I get:

> graphviz.dot.Digraph has no built-in viewer support for
>   'pdf' on 'linux' platform

I got the same error trying svg, png, etc.

I did this because of Python 3.3:

```
pip install graphviz
pip install pydot2
```

I want to use something that allows displaying great visualizations using Python and do some clustering according to some attribute of the nodes.

Do you know something that is better than Graphviz for that need?

(I would like to try something else. I've already tried networkx, but I can't obtain good visualizations. I can't have the length I want for edges and nx.draw_graphviz does not work either...)

Comment: Try `g.render()` instead of `g.view()`, you might have to open the resulting file manually but it should produce something at least.

Comment: I think it saves only the dot file. I'm not able to get png or another format.

Comment: why anaconda, and not the distributions proper python?

Comment: Because Anaconda is a Python distribution for data analytics,
processing, and scientific computing. And because it comes with a lot of packages. I think I'm going to try to get Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 together, I don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Not python related but for a quick preview you can use: http://www.webgraphviz.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Nice to know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the second question:

> I want to use something that allows displaying great visualizations using Python and do some clustering according to some attribute of the nodes.
>
> Do you know something that is better than Graphviz for that need?

I've found that the module [`graph-tool`](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) does everything that `networkx` can do and more. In my personal opinion, the rendering interface is a bit nicer, and it's less work to get a nice looking graph. This is especially true for directed graphs which are horrible using networkx. Graphviz is a bit better, but it still requires a lot of up front configuration. An example from the website:

[image]

Comment: I've looked at it also. How to make it work with anaconda Python 3.3 ? Nothing works ! lool It said me looking for "m4" and I've conda install m4 and seems not to be the good "m4".